# What is the difference between the .po .mo and .pot localization files?

Tags: localization, filesystem

I'm translating a wordpress site and need more clarity around these terms. Can anyone please lend a hand with some definitions and differences between .po .mo and .pot files with wordpress localization?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

These are not any kind of WP's own format but rather just gettext file types which WP implements.

Translate Handbook has following definitions in its [Glossary](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/glossary/):

> MO files: MO, or Machine Object is a binary data file that contains
>   object data referenced by a program. It is typically used to translate
>   program code, and may be loaded or imported into the GNU gettext
>   program.
>
> PO files: PO files are the files which contain the actual
>   translations. Each language will have its own PO file, for example,
>   for French there would be a fr.po file, for german there would be a
>   de.po, for American English there might be en-US.po.
>
> POT file: POT files are the template files for PO files. They will
>   have all the translation strings left empty. A POT file is essentially
>   an empty PO file without the translations, with just the original
>   strings.

The technical details of file formats can be found in gettext documentation:

- [The Format of PO Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html#PO-Files)
- [The Format of GNU MO Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/MO-Files.html#MO-Files)

Comment: So, to understand it better, in a nutshell mo and pot files are left intact (mo file is essentially made automatically by using a program, for example poedit)? I still dont understand when we need a pot file..

Comment: POT file is used whenever someone starts a new PO file for translation to a new language. So the workflow is POT (original strings) to PO (original strings and their translation to a specific language) to MO (compiled binary result).

Comment: You mean that for translations in a theme to work, there must be a translation which begins from importing to poedit a .pot file? I was ignoring the pot file (because theme I was looking for only is locale ready, not language-ready and had no pot files provided) and I could see no change of the language after customizing the en-EN.po and .mo files to my preferred language.

Comment: I would advise to just ask a new question. :) You are dragging your very specific problem (customization not working) into a very general questions (what are the file formats).

Comment: any good online reference about these files

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi I have added links to technical details, if you are curious about internals. :)

Comment: I am getting a couple of .mo files added and thought it might be a hack because of the encoded 'junk' inside. Could these files keep being generated innocently- path is /wp-content/languages/themes/twentytwenty-en_GB.mo

Comment: @landed yes, `mo` files are _binary_ format, they are not supposed to be human-readable.

Comment: Could .mo files contain hackers code? I am puzzled as I even uninstalled this theme so what is creating these files?

Comment: What does "PO" stand for?

Comment: That would be Portable Object.